# See device intranet page via external IP address or DynDNS url

Tags: linux, dns, localhost, router

I have a device that have the configuration page. I setup port forwarding in the router. It works fine when access from outside via public IP so I map that public IP to a DynDNS url. Sweet! easy access for our customer. 
However within the building it cant be accessed via the DynDNS url or its public IP. I google it and see the problem is at NAT loopback but the router doesnt have NAT loopback setting? Is there other way that I can setup to access the device by a DynDNS url no matter my customer is inside or outside of the LAN? Just to keep thing simple for our customer.

Thanks very much for any suggestion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The address is (hopefully) static inside the subnet. I would configure a caching DNS server in the subnet to return the internal IP and then forward any other DNS requests out to whatever DNS server they use (probably the ISP).

EDIT: research [BIND views](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch7/view.html)

It sounds like the easiest config would be build a caching DNS server with internal and external views.

Comment: Yep it's static internally. Does it mean that I need to configure a local DNS server in the network and edit the vhost to redirect to the local IP if user browser to the url of the device. All other urls will be resolved by ISP DNS server.

Comment: Whois info should always be configured correctly for the public side. If this is just one or two clients, I'd probably suggest simply adding a `hosts` entry on those clients. If a larger audience, then yes, I'd suggest an LDNS, possibly with multiple views.